# skip a folder name in path while displaying in address bar

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, hide

I want a folder name not to be displayed in address bar. Example: hiding "members" folder:

www.mysite.com/members/jonesmith/index.php

www.mysite.com/members/tome/index.php

www.mysite.com/members/jerry/index.php

...etc

I want to put those links like this:

www.mysite.com/jonesmith/index.php

www.mysite.com//tome/index.php

www.mysite.com/jerry/index.php

...etc

and when the link is clicked the address bar will show the same, i.e, without "members".

I need this make the pages of the members or the urls short.

Of course any link clicked within the pages of the member will not show the "members" in address bar.

Shortly: the folder "members" exists but it will not be visible to the visitors in every level.

Any idea using php script, javascript, .htaccess ..etc?

Comment: As long as you don't link to it, it won't be shown in the address bar. What's that complicated?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Apache you can use the mod_rewrite module for this.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/

I'm sure IIS support somthing like that to.

Answer (score -1):

You can use .htaccess with mod_rewrite to rewrite URLs by pre-pending /members to them.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /~user

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/~user/members/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~user/members/$1 [L]
```

I imagine removing the ~user for your setup might work, but my test rewrites paths like /~user/a/image.gif -> /~user/members/a/image.gif.

Perhaps a more complete solution is in the following thread, which adds some rules to remove the hidden sub-directory if someone gives a URL with it included:
http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3588649.htm